# Web Workers Stop/Halt the mobile UI

Tags: cordova, web-worker

I am using JavaScript Web Workers in cordova application in order to do some long activity in background while my main thread execute as normally.

I am using below code snippet:

```
 var worker = new Worker('sync_worker.js');
 worker.postMessage("test");
```

My sync_worker.js contain a simple infinite loop for testing now.

```
function syncArticles()
{
   var ten = 1
   while (ten = 1)
   {
     console.log("infinite loop");
   }
 }

syncArticles();
```

However the Worker stops my main thread and as a result UI halts.

Any help why it sops my main threas i.e. UI?

Comment: What happens if you remove the console.log?

Comment: After removing  console.log() UI never halts. so i should never use console.log() in web worker background activity?